# SQL Server : subquery return same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am still learning SQL so please forgive the blatant mistakes. I came up with the following script, I basically need to list daily information for each column. I might have overdone the subqueries as they are returning the same values, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. the end goal is to get a functional query I can pull into SSRS.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(date, d.ts) 'Date', 
    s.StoreId 'Store No.', 
    s.Description,
    h.NetTotalPrice,
    b.BudgetAmt,
    eod.BalanceAmount'Electronic Deposit', 
    h.custID'Cust Count',
    c.TotalTransactions'NumTrans',
    c.TotalSales,

    --departments subqueries  
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Accessories' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'ACCESSORIES',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Books' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'BOOKS',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Electronics' OR dep.deptID = 'Electrical and mechanical' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'E&M',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Furniture' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'FURNITURE',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Linen' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'LINEN',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Shoes'
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'SHOES',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Textiles' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'TEXTILES',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Wares' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'WARES',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Cash over/short' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'CASHOVER(SHORT)',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Found Money' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'Found Money',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Gift Card Purchased' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'Purchased GiftCard',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON h.storeID = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Gift Card Redeemed' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'Redeemed GiftCard',

    --Discounts Subqueries 
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(h.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
     INNER JOIN tblTransSalesPmt pmt WITH (nolock) ON pmt.storeID = h.storeID
     WHERE pmt.PmtMethodId = 'Mission$' 
     GROUP BY h.StoreId) 'Vouchers Money$',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(d.TotalDiscount) 
     FROM tblTransSalesDtl d WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblTransSalesLineDiscount ld WITH (nolock) ON d.StoreId = ld.StoreId AND d.TransId = ld.TransId
     WHERE ld.DiscountType = 'COTW' 
     GROUP BY CONVERT(date, d.ts)) 'Color Disc',
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(d.TotalDiscount) 
     FROM tblTransSalesDtl d WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblTransSalesLineDiscount ld WITH (nolock) ON d.StoreId = ld.StoreId AND d.TransId = ld.TransId
     WHERE ld.DiscountType = 'PROMO-Employee'
     GROUP BY CONVERT(date, d.ts)) 'Employee Disc', 
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(d.TotalDiscount) 
     FROM tblTransSalesDtl d WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblTransSalesLineDiscount ld WITH (nolock) ON d.StoreId = ld.StoreId AND d.TransId = ld.TransId
     WHERE ld.DiscountType = 'PROMO-99 Sunday'
     GROUP BY CONVERT(date, d.ts)) 'Sunday Disc'
FROM
    tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 
INNER JOIN 
    tblTransSalesDtl d WITH (nolock) ON h.TransId = d.TransId 
                                     AND h.StoreId = d.StoreId
INNER JOIN 
    tblRptSalesByCategory c WITH (nolock) ON c.StoreId = d.StoreId
INNER JOIN 
    tblEODDrawerTotal eod WITH (nolock) ON eod.StoreId =c.StoreId
INNER JOIN 
    tblStore s WITH (nolock) ON eod.StoreId = s.StoreId
INNER JOIN 
    tbldept dep WITH (nolock) ON dep.StoreId = s.StoreId
LEFT JOIN 
    tblBudgetDaily b WITH (nolock) ON dep.StoreId = b.StoreId 
                                   AND dep.DeptId = b.DeptID 
WHERE 
    Status = 3
```

the Output is looking like this:
[image]

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Since you are accessing tblTransSalesHdr so many times, it is probably way faster to use a PIVOT.  Not basic SQL, but well worth using in a case such as yours.

Comment: @eshirvana It's not letting me export the data but I've updated the post with an image of what it looks like.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: @RobertSievers I did not realize it was possible to use pivots in SSMS, I'll do some research on that right away. The reason for using SQL is that I was trying to come up with a complete data set which I could then commit to a table and pull into an SSRS report.

Comment: @SMor care to expand on why. I was advice to do so as to not freeze the system, but I guess I can try without it.

Comment: Read the link! And your subqueries are logically incorrect. You know this because you tried to use TOP 1 as a kludge around your logic fault. Those subqueries need to be correlated to the outer query. They should not be grouping by anything since a group by clause will generally cause a query to produce multiple rows, but I have no idea what your subqueries are supposed to calculate based on the content of the outer query - i.e., how they should be correlated.

Comment: In reference to @Smor 's comment, [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: And you want to join `tblTransSalesHdr` then either `PIVOT` or conditional aggregation `SUM(CASE WHEN dep.DeptID = 'Gift Card Redeemed'...`

Comment: And if someone is advising you to use hints, then those persons are also the ones that you should ask for help. The fact that they suggest hints is not a good sign but they should be able to advise you on which tables to use, how to join them, etc. I find the use of table tblTransSalesDtl suspicious - but I don't know your schema. If you want daily information, somewhere it seems you should be summing and grouping by date. Maybe it would be better for you to start over, remove all the beautification columns (and related joins) and just calculate daily numbers for a small set of dates.

Comment: @SMor thank you for those bits of info I am trying to use any guidance I can. the subquery are essentially an attempt at determining for example "the daily NetTotalPrice per department" but since I wanted a separate column to show the info I tried to use subqueries. I'll also starting over on a different query

Comment: add outer table join to subquery? 

```sql
SELECT
    h.StoreId 'Store No.', 
    --departments subqueries  
    (SELECT SUM(ih.NetTotalPrice) 
     FROM tblTransSalesHdr ih WITH (nolock) 
     LEFT JOIN tblDept dep ON ih.StoreId = dep.StoreId
     WHERE dep.DeptID = 'Accessories' 
  AND ih.StoreId = h.StoreId) 'ACCESSORIES'
FROM
    tblTransSalesHdr h WITH (nolock) 

```